# Javascript window.location returning two different values?

Tags: javascript

I am using a JS popup window for an Oauth2 Implicit Grant. I'm using JS to monitor for URL changes to get the code grant.

```
    newWindow.addEventListener('unload', function(e)
    {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.location);

        if (e.currentTarget.location.href.includes('code='))
        {
            var url = new URL(e.currentTarget.location.href);
            alert(url.searchParams.get('code'));
        }
    });
```

The problem I am having is that the `location` field is giving two different values for the `href` parameter.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the href parameter has two different values. How do I make sure I always get the second value?

Comment: What does `e.currentTarget.location.href` show?

Comment: `about:blank`... but console.log lists the other address in the drop down.

Comment: What's the actual page URL?

Comment: the second one.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod Is the question is related to `console` values, working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Location* is evaluated some time before.

If you hover over the little blue *i* icon, it says:

> Value below was evaluated just now.

Comment: So what is the solution here?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, to me, the solution is to avoid *console* when possible.

Comment: I thought the `Jason` Getting the first one, that's why posted a question!